# parse error, when moving pipe to shared module

Tags: angular

I have a pipe that successfully runs when declared in a component module, when I try to move this declaration to a shared module (as I need to use this pipe in many components). I get a parse error in my HTML indicating it can not find the pipe.

the pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Relations } from '../helpers/relations';

@Pipe({
    name: 'lookupRelation'
})
@NgModule()
export class LookupRelationPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any ): any {
        return new Relations().getType(value);
    }
}
```

shared module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LookupRelationPipe } from '../pipes/lookup.relation.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ 
      LookupRelationPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    LookupRelationPipe
  ] 
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

component module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BeneficiaryRoutingModule } from './beneficiary-routing.module';
import { BeneficiaryListComponent } from './beneficiary-list/beneficiary-list.component';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from '../angular-materials.module';

import { BeneficiaryDialog } from './beneficiary.dialog/beneficiary.dialog';
import { LookupContacttypePipe } from '../pipes/lookup-contacttype.pipe';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
//import { LookupRelationPipe } from '../pipes/lookup.relation.pipe'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BeneficiaryListComponent, 
    BeneficiaryDialog, 
    LookupContacttypePipe
  //  LookupRelationPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BeneficiaryRoutingModule,
    AngularMaterialModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [BeneficiaryDialog]
})
export class BeneficiaryModule { }
```

Note: when I uncomment the pipe deceleration in this module, the app executes successfully.

html

```
...
           <ng-container matColumnDef="relation">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Relation</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.relation | lookupRelation }}</td>
              </ng-container>

....
```

I get a parse error indicating the pipe cannot be found when I move the declaration to the shared module, where the pipe executes successfully if declared in the component module. It should also be noted that the CommonModule and forms module are working ok when I moved them to the same shared module (and removed the imports from the component module).

Comment: Close the terminal and run the project again because sometimes if we add the another module in parent module we need to restart the project.

Comment: let me know if it is working or not

Comment: Yashi, unfortunately not.

Comment: Can you remove the `@NgModule()` from you pipe ts

Comment: still same error :(

Comment: Yashi, after restarting -- with the superfluous @NgModule decorator removed -- problem solved. ty

Comment: Great!!!! it would be great if you accept my answer.